# How do I pass the image created by todataurl.js to MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a script that captures a signature via touch screen or mouse pad and I want to take that image that the todataurl.js creates and upload it to a folder on my server so I can store the path to the image. But I don't know how to get the image from the todataurl.js script.

here is the HTML and javascript I'm using. Also this is a prototype script and there is no documentation on it whatsoever! I tried to put this as a jsFiddle but couldn't get it to function on the site. The script works fine, I just can't figure out how to get the image to upload. All I get now when I click on the get signature button is the name of the the image field in MySQL.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="signature/todataurl.js"></script>
    <script src="signature/signature.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div id="canvas">
        <canvas class="roundCorners" id="newSignature"
          style="position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0;
          border: 1px solid #c4caac; left: 0px; top: 0px;" height="124" width="524">
        </canvas>
      </div>
      <script>signatureCapture();</script>
      <br/><br/>
      <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="signatureSave()">
        Save signature
      </button>
      <button type="button" onclick="signatureClear()">
        Clear signature
      </button>
      <br/>
      Saved Image
      <br/>
      <img  name="get_signature" id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png"/>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

signature.js code:

```
function signatureCapture() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 276;
  canvas.height = 180;
  context.fillStyle = "#fff";
  context.strokeStyle = "#444";
  context.lineWidth = 1.5;
  context.lineCap = "round";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var disableSave = true;
  var pixels = [];
  var cpixels = [];
  var xyLast = {};
  var xyAddLast = {};
  var calculate = false;
  {   //functions
    function remove_event_listeners() {
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
      canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
      document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
      document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
    }
    function get_coords(e) {
      var x, y;
      if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
        var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
        var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;
        x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
        y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
      } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
      } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
      }
      return {
        x : x,
        y : y
      };
    };
    function on_mousedown(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
      document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
      document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
      empty = false;
      var xy = get_coords(e);
      context.beginPath();
      pixels.push('moveStart');
      context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
      pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
      xyLast = xy;
    };
    function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      var xy = get_coords(e);
      var xyAdd = {
        x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
        y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
      };
      if (calculate) {
        var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
        var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
        pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
      } else {
        calculate = true;
      }
      context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
      pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
      context.stroke();
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
      xyAddLast = xyAdd;
      xyLast = xy;
    };
    function on_mouseup(e) {
      remove_event_listeners();
      disableSave = false;
      context.stroke();
      pixels.push('e');
      calculate = false;
    };
  }
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
}
function signatureSave() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;
};
function signatureClear() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

todataurl.js code:

```
Number.prototype.toUInt=function(){ return this<0?this+4294967296:this; };
Number.prototype.bytes32=function(){
  return [(this>>>24)&0xff,(this>>>16)&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff,this&0xff];
};
Number.prototype.bytes32sw=function(){
  return [this&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff,(this>>>16)&0xff,(this>>>24)&0xff];
};
Number.prototype.bytes16=function(){
  return [(this>>>8)&0xff,this&0xff];
};
Number.prototype.bytes16sw=function(){
  return [this&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff];
};
Array.prototype.adler32=function(start,len){
  switch(arguments.length){ case 0:start=0; case 1:len=this.length-start; }
  var a=1,b=0;
  for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    a = (a+this[start+i])%65521; b = (b+a)%65521;
  }
  return ((b << 16) | a).toUInt();
};
Array.prototype.crc32=function(start,len){
  switch(arguments.length){ case 0:start=0; case 1:len=this.length-start; }
  var table=arguments.callee.crctable;
  if(!table){
    table=[];
    var c;
    for (var n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
      c = n;
      for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        c = c & 1?0xedb88320 ^ (c >>> 1):c >>> 1;
      table[n] = c.toUInt();
    }
    arguments.callee.crctable=table;
  }
  var c = 0xffffffff;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    c = table[(c ^ this[start+i]) & 0xff] ^ (c>>>8);
  return (c^0xffffffff).toUInt();
};
(function(){
  var toDataURL=function(){
    var imageData=Array.prototype.slice.call(this.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height).data);
    var w=this.width;
    var h=this.height;
    var stream=[
      0x89,0x50,0x4e,0x47,0x0d,0x0a,0x1a,0x0a,
      0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0d,0x49,0x48,0x44,0x52
    ];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, w.bytes32() );
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, h.bytes32() );
    stream.push(0x08,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(12,17).bytes32() );
    var len=h*(w*4+1);
    for(var y=0;y<h;y++)
      imageData.splice(y*(w*4+1),0,0);
    var blocks=Math.ceil(len/32768);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (len+5*blocks+6).bytes32() );
    var crcStart=stream.length;
    var crcLen=(len+5*blocks+6+4);
    stream.push(0x49,0x44,0x41,0x54,0x78,0x01);
    for(var i=0;i<blocks;i++){
      var blockLen=Math.min(32768,len-(i*32768));
      stream.push(i==(blocks-1)?0x01:0x00);
      Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, blockLen.bytes16sw() );
      Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (~blockLen).bytes16sw() );
      var id=imageData.slice(i*32768,i*32768+blockLen);
      Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, id );
    }
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, imageData.adler32().bytes32() );
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(crcStart, crcLen).bytes32() );
    stream.push(0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x49,0x45,0x4e,0x44);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(stream.length-4, 4).bytes32() );
    return "data:image/png;base64,"+btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,stream));
  };
  var tdu=HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;
  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=function(type){
  var res=tdu.apply(this,arguments);
  if(res.substr(0,6)=="data:,") {
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=toDataURL;
    return this.toDataURL();
  } else {
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=tdu;
    return res;
  }
}
})();
```

UPDATED TO ADD BELOW CODE FOR SCRIPT THAT PROCESSES PAGE TO MYSQL:

```
    <?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "sig/uploads/images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['imageData']['name']);
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $_POST['imageData'])));
$customer_signature=( $_FILES['imageData']['name']);
//This gets all the other information from the form

// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (customer_signature)
VALUES ('$customer_signature')") ;
echo mysql_error(); 
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageData']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['imageData']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toDataURL()` creates a string from your canvas image, I'm guessing this is sent to your server to save it by that javascript. Are you processing this to save your image on the server?

The string sent starts with something like

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

followed by the actual image converted to Base 64.

- Update

Sending the image string to your server:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "script.php",
  data: { 
     imageString: canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  },
  success: function(response){ alert("image sent"); },
  error: function(xhr, status, error){ alert("there was an error sending the image" + error); },
});
```

You can put this in your `signatureSave()` function.
On server side, in `script.php` you can simply grab the string with `$_POST['imageString']`, remove the identifying part from it (`data:image/png;base64,`) and Base64 decode the rest of the string then save it.

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $_POST['imageData])));
imagepng("path/to/save/yourimage.png");
```

Comment: Yes I want to save the image in a folder and store that path in MySQL. I know how to do the MySQL portion I just don't know how to get the image from the todataurl.js I don't know anything about javascript and I've been searching this todataurl for weeks trying to figure out how it's saving the image, if it's even saving it at all.

Comment: do you have the php which saves the image?

Comment: yes I'm already doing it with my inventory code I just need to figure out how to get the image from the todataurl

Comment: sorry if I'm asking a stupid question but I want to make sure I understand this correctly. So the script.php would actually be my script that processes the signature image to the db which would be process_signature.php correct? and I would add the $image=imagecreatefromstring...... as my variable and add my file path to the string correct?  I'm lost on the signatureSave() part though.

Comment: Updated Question to include my php script that posts to the db and uploads the image. I already have a variable that tells the path for the image to be uploaded to so I removed the path section from your code I want to make sure what I have is correct.

Comment: Almost, there's no file upload so you don't need all that. Basically my two lines of php does all you need: catch the image and save it to the server. All you would need to add is to save the path to mysql too.

Comment: so I'm still confused as to what the variable is that used to insert the path into MySQL. My table name is customer_signature and my value is $customer_signature, I'm lost as to how the script will populate the path into that table with your two lines.

Comment: Also adding the ajax portion to the signaturesave function causes the script to not work, I can't draw on the canvas unless I remove that section.

Comment: What is the error message in your console? The filename is whatever you give to that file, it doesn't matter.

Comment: There is no error message I just can't draw on the canvas, I dropped the ajax code u suggested at the end of the signatureSave() function and now I can't draw on the canvas. well it helps if I use firfox here is one error [04:59:13.128] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @ http://localhost/alpha/development/signature/signature.js:119

Comment: 119 would be part of the ajax section you had me add, it's the data: {

Comment: yeah, you're right, there is an error. remove the `;` after `image/png")` and it should work just fine.

Comment: ok that fixed that issue I can draw on the canvas but it's not posting the image to the db

Comment: with firebug opened when you post the image you can see the response from the server, if there's an error you'll find it there.

Comment: it say's the $ in $.ajax is not defined

Comment: :) I automatically assumed you are using jQuery. You can get it from here http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js

Comment: yeah it's still not working a bunch of undefined errors now when I added those two lines to my process_signature.php

Comment: I'd move this to chat but don't have the reputation to do it, anyway it's posting to the database it just isn't posting the image or the path. I think this would be easier if I could just save the image to a file and have my script upload it